# Apply Rotation on downloaded, appended eye model resets original rotation and it's driving me crazy

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, transforms, append

I’ve downloaded a very simple eyeball with a jpeg texture, and when appending to a file I am unable to apply the correction rotation. When I apply, the eyeball flips exactly 180 degrees. Thus I am unable to use it in any eye socket of a character. Interestingly, it flips 180 degrees on either the x or z axis to the exact same position (whereas the rotation is really only on the x axis). I can apply scale and location, but not rotation.

File is linked please help. I’m sure it’s so simple. thank you
[single eye file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/11Gr0Lh--cppGXbq6umbJIDJYV-dycr9a/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: why do you want to apply the rotation?

Comment: Hello :). Could you please add your node setup? For those who can't download the file.

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with your *Texture Coordinate* and *Image Texture* settings, choose the *UV* output socket instead of *Generated* and choose *Flat* instead of *Sphere*. Choosing *Generated* makes the pupil come back to front when you apply the rotation, which is not what you want:

[image]

Or you can put a *Mapping* node between these 2 nodes and play with the rotation values.

Comment: Thanks all for your quick replies. Chris, I wanted to join the eyes with the head base mesh instead of parenting, as I wasn't planning on deformation with this model, and joining just seemed easier than parenting. But the rotation kept flipping when trying to join. So I thought applying the rotation would fix the flip problem. Since it was a node issue that wasn't really the case anyway. That was the trick, moonboots, tks much.